# Keras CNN, High training while low testing, each time my training increase, the validation decrease

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

am doing a text classification, my dataset size is 16000 KB, my problem is I have 95% of training and 90% in testing, I have some values are zero in my dataset, is that effect ?.. can I increase testing ? and how?
[here is my training and validation curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRw1d.png)

here is my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D( filters=256,kernel_size=5, activation = 'relu',input_shape=(7,1)))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=200,
                    verbose=True,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    batch_size=128)
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=True)
print("Training Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=False)
print("Testing Accuracy:  {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
```

Comment: what are your transforms on the images?

Comment: my dataset are text not images.. but  I have some values are zero in my dataset, is that effect ? @DwightFoster

Comment: That may affect how good it is at guessing but your dataset might also be too small. It is definitely overfitting but I am not 100% sure why. How much of your dataset is zeros? and what are you trying to predict?

Comment: Tring to predict the category of the document, such as culture, medical, technology, sport.  my dataset is large enough it is almost 98000 document and I cannot count the number of zeros cause I have feature for each class and some of these feature in a particular class is zero. @DwightFoster

Comment: Hmm okay I am not 100% sure then. I do not think the zeros should affect it this much. When you load the data are you shuffling it? If you already are then the only advice I can give you is try to mess around with your model size and learning rate to see if you can improve it.

Comment: what do you mean by shuffling? I loaded them In sequence from the first category to the last one, and I give each category a  number, like first category is zero and second category is 2.. etc. @DwightFoster

Comment: What I mean is when you pass the dataset to the model with the 98000 documents and labels do you randomize there order. Because the model might just be memorizing the order they are in.

Comment: I give the random state =0 @DwightFoster